# Creating an additional dataframe using two existing dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

**Input Data Frame**

Data Frame 1 (example - nrow = 100)

```
Col A | Col B | Col C
  a       1       2    
  a       3       4    
  b       5       6    
  c       9      10
```

Data frame 2 (example - nrow = 200)

```
Col A | Col B | Col E
  a       1       22    
  a       31      41    
  a       3       63    
  b       5       6
  b       11      13   
  c       9       20
```

I want to create a third data set which contains each of the additional row found in the Data Frame 2 for the Col A entry.

**Output File** (nrow = 200-100 = 100)

```
Col A | Col B | Col E
  a       31      41    
  b       11      13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need it in a loop, create an empty dataset with the column names of the second dataset.  Loop over the `unique` values of 'ColA' from second dataset, `subset` the 'df2', get the difference in number of rows between the subset and the corresponding row of 'df1' ('cnt'), `rbind` the 'out' with the `tail` of the subset of dataset

```
#// Create an empty dataset structure
out <- data.frame(ColA = character(), ColD = numeric(), ColE = numeric()) 
# // Get the unique values of the column 
un1 <- unique(df2$ColA)
# // Loop over the unique values
for(un in un1)  {
        # // subset the dataset df2
        tmp <- subset(df2, ColA == un)
        # // get a difference in row count
        cnt <- nrow(tmp) - sum(df1$ColA == un)
        # // use the count to subset the subset of df2
        # // rbind and assign back to the original out
        out <- rbind(out, tail(tmp, cnt))
}

row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#  ColA ColD ColE
#1    a   51   63
#2    b   11   13
```

---

For multiple columns, we could `paste` to create a single column

```
df1 <- data.frame(ColA = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ColB = c(1, 3, 5, 9), 
      ColC = c(2, 4, 6, 10))
df2 <- data.frame(ColA = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'), 
     ColB = c(1, 31, 3, 5, 11, 9), ColE = c(22, 41, 63, 6, 13, 20))
```

create the function

```
f1 <- function(data1, data2, by_cols) {
           # // Create an empty dataset structure
           
           # // Get the unique value by pasteing the by_cols
           data2$new <- do.call(paste, data2[by_cols])
           data1$new <- do.call(paste, data1[by_cols])
           out <- data2[0,]
           un1 <- unique(data2$new)
          

           # // Loop over the unique values
           for(un in un1) {
                # // subset the second dataset              
                tmp <- subset(data2, new == un)
              
                # // get the difference in row count
                cnt <- nrow(tmp) - sum(data1$new == un)
               
                # // use the count to subet the subset of data2
                # // rbind and assign back to the original out
                out <- rbind(out, tail(tmp, cnt))
              }
            out$new <- NULL
            row.names(out) <- NULL
            out
         }
f1(df1, df2, c("ColA", "ColB"))
# ColA ColB ColE
#1    a   31   41
#2    b   11   13
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColA = c("a", "a", "b", "c"), ColB = c(1, 3, 5, 
9), ColC = c(2, 4, 6, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(ColA = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), ColD = c(12, 
31, 51, 71, 11, 93), ColE = c(22, 41, 63, 86, 13, 20)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: What change would we have to make in the code if we make use to an additional column (ColB) to select the row that we add in the data "out". Now, we no longer remove the last row, but the row in which the colB value do not match. Please see the change I made in the data frame 1 and data frame 2 in the input data frames.

Comment: @AashayMehta please post as a new question

Answer (score 2):

You could add row numbers to each data frame, and then do an `anti_join`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  group_by(colA) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  anti_join(df1 %>% group_by(colA) %>% mutate(rn = row_number())) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   colA [2]
  colA   colD  colE
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        51    63
2 b        11    13
```

Comment: Can we accomplish this using a for loop??

Comment: @AashayMehta Yes, but could you describe further your interest here? Did you want to loop by `colA` groups, and compare the 2 data frames? Did you need to include any additional operations when comparing the two data frames? I would guess there may be multiple approaches for what you need.

Comment: Since I have multiple columns in both the data set and the names of df2 (ncol = 10) are identical to the names of df1 (ncol = 100), using the apporach of pipeline is creating a different output. I am sorry I should have been more careful with the column names while I posted this question. Further, I was trying to solve this problem using a for loop myself, therefore I wanted to learn doing it using a For Loop. Yes, I want to loop by ```ColA``` but i dont want to perform any additional operation when looping. I just want to create a new df with the additional entry found in df2.